# How to enforce order in regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

In my Rails app I have this regular expression:

```
/\A(?:\{(?:YYYY|YY|MM|DD|N{2,6})\}|[A-Za-z_.#-])*\z/
```

It matches for example a string like this: `{YY}{MM}{DD}{NNNN}`

Is there a way to enforce the order of `{YY}`,`{MM}`,`{DD}`, and `{NN}`, so that for example...

`{DD}{MM}{YY}{NNNN}`

... will not be valid?

To make this even more complicated, letters, dashes, and underscores should be allowed between those elements as well.

So this string should be valid too:

`{YY}-{MM}-{DD}_{NNNN}`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: No, not completely, from what I can see.  Example: The number `12` could be a day, month, or year (2012 or maybe 1912), and you can't know without seeing the context.  You _could_ specify ranges for each component, but that's a lot of work.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I misunderstood your question. You were *literally* trying to match the string YYMMDDNN.

Comment: Yeah, my question is indeed a little misleading. I literally need those letters to build a regular expression which gets saved to the database.

Comment: You could prepend a positive lookahead to your regex `\A(?={YY(YY)?}.{MM}.{DD}.{NN{2,6}}\z)`. See demo here http://rubular.com/r/LOUsKVEMsf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure an order, your regex needs to make sure that order is used. Currently you're just looking for `YY`, `MM`, etc. individually. Instead you can do something like this:

```
\A(\{YY(YY)?\}\{MM\}\{DD\}\{N{2,6}\}|[A-Za-z_.#-])*\z
```

To allow dashes or underscores in between the parts you can now add them easily:

```
\A(\{YY(YY)?\}[-_A-Za-z]*\{MM\}[-_A-Za-z]*\{DD\}[-_A-Za-z]*\{N{2,6}\}|[A-Za-z_.#-])*\z
```

Comment: Thanks. This is already a million times better than anything I came up with so far. I am still getting an `Unmatched close parenthesis` error on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/sF4kAiVFYv), though. Currently trying to figure out why...

Comment: I forgot to open one, and copied the closing one from your question

Answer (score 1):

Currently your regex matches any sequence of letters i.e. `abcde`. Besides you need to let one character from `[A-Za-z_.#-]` set to reside between curly braces - optionally. On Ruby >=1.9 below regex with invoking subroutine calls works well:

```
\A{YY(?:YY)?}([A-Za-z_.#-]?){MM}\g<1>{DD}\g<1>{N{2,6}}\z
```

[Live demo](http://rubular.com/r/c5U37Lnspl)

Comment: Looking cool, thanks. I should explore those `g<1>` bits a bit more. Never seen those before...

Comment: You're welcome. You can find more details about them on this [documentation page](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Subexpression+Calls). Also I'm not sure if matching `abcde` is a requirement... if not you would better ask the other answer's author to modify their answer. Otherwise it will be misleading for any future reader as they will count on the accepted answer more.